# In Python 3, is it possible to use short-circuit evaluation in an any call that doesn't have a for .. in expression in it?

Tags: python-3.x, short-circuit-evaluation

In Python 3, is it possible to use short-circuit evaluation in an `any` call that doesn't have a `for .. in` expression in it?

I know that I can take advantage of short-circuit evaluation in a statement like this:

```
print('Hello' if True or 3/0 else 'World')  # this prints "Hello"
```

But if I try something similar with `any`, I get an exception because the `3/0` is evaluated:

```
print('Hello' if any([True, 3/0]) else 'World')  # this raises an exception
```

Is there a way I can use `any` to do this?

Comment: Probably not—the problem is that you've now materialized the list.

Comment: `map` is a looping construct but does not have `for ... in`. For example: `any(map(int,'0000001'))`

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is not `any`, it is the immediate evaluation of `3/0` as the list literal is evaluated:

```
>>> [True, 3/0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

The only way to avoid that is to delay the evaluation until a later time with the use of a function or iterator:

```
def f(e):
    return e[0]/e[1] if isinstance(e,(list,tuple)) else e

>>> print('Hello' if any(map(f, [True, [3,0]])) else 'World')
Hello
```